# Stuck on using multiple pipes in C

Tags: c, unix, pipe, piping

I'm writing a program that just chains together specifically 3 programs, etc "ls | sort | wc".

I looked through the other posts I found on google about multiple pipes but I still can't figure out what I've been doing wrong. Been stuck on this for a while. I believe my program is logically correct, but for some reason it doesn't run. What am I missing?

```
pipe(pipe1);
pipe(pipe2);

pid = fork();
if(pid > 0){
    close(pipe2[1]);
    dup2(pipe2[0], 0);
    execlp(argv[3], argv[3], NULL);
}
else if(pid == 0){
    pid2 = fork();
    if(pid2 == 0){
        close(pipe1[0]);
        dup2(pipe1[1], 1);
        execlp(argv[1], argv[1], NULL);
    }
    else if(pid2 > 0){
        close(pipe1[1]);
        dup2(pipe1[0], 0);
        close(pipe2[0]);
        dup2(pipe2[1], 1);
        execlp(argv[2], argv[2], NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does your command look?

Comment: i run from the command line and i just have it take 3 arguments, so it'll be ./programname ls sort wc. The output shows nothing but doesn't exit so i guess there's an infinite loop somewhere because I somehow messed up my pipe connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fork three times each time in the parent cases, and execute your commands only inside the child cases. Take a look [here](https://gist.github.com/mplewis/5279108)

Adjusted to your case:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  int pid;
  int pipe1[2];
  int pipe2[2];

  // create pipe1
  if (pipe(pipe1) == -1) {
    perror("bad pipe1");
    exit(1);
  }

  // fork (ps aux)
  if ((pid = fork()) == -1) {
    perror("bad fork1");
    exit(1);
  } 
  else if (pid == 0) {
    // stdin --> ps --> pipe1
    // input from stdin (already done), output to pipe1
    dup2(pipe1[1], 1);
    // close fds
    close(pipe1[0]);
    close(pipe1[1]);

    execlp(argv[1], argv[1], NULL);
    // exec didn't work, exit
    perror("bad exec ps");
    _exit(1);
  }
  // parent

  // create pipe2
  if (pipe(pipe2) == -1) {
    perror("bad pipe2");
    exit(1);
  }

  // fork (grep root)
  if ((pid = fork()) == -1) {
    perror("bad fork2");
    exit(1);
  } 
  else if (pid == 0) {
    // pipe1 --> grep --> pipe2
    // input from pipe1
    dup2(pipe1[0], 0);
    // output to pipe2
    dup2(pipe2[1], 1);
    // close fds
    close(pipe1[0]);
    close(pipe1[1]);
    close(pipe2[0]);
    close(pipe2[1]);

    execlp(argv[2], argv[2], NULL);
    // exec didn't work, exit
    perror("bad exec grep root");
    _exit(1);
  }
  // parent

  // close unused fds
  close(pipe1[0]);
  close(pipe1[1]);

  // fork (grep sbin)
  if ((pid = fork()) == -1) {
    perror("bad fork3");
    exit(1);
  } 
  else if (pid == 0) {
    // pipe2 --> grep --> stdout
    // input from pipe2
    dup2(pipe2[0], 0);
    // output to stdout (already done). Close fds
    close(pipe2[0]);
    close(pipe2[1]);

    execlp(argv[3], argv[3], NULL);
    // exec didn't work, exit
    perror("bad exec grep sbin");
    _exit(1);
  }
  // parent

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured out what was wrong with my code. I was thinking why forking 3 times in the parent would be different from what I did, and I don't think there's any difference. But what I did wrong was I didn't close pipe1 in the parent process like you did. I added that and the code now works.

Comment: oh I didn't notice that. Good job ;)

Answer (score 0):

I find another solution, the parent process treats the first command, write its output in the first pipe and create a child which will treat the second command and write its outputin the second pipe, meanwhile this child will create a sub-child which will treat the third command.

the command is : ls -l | grep "sthg" `| wc -l

```
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(){
int p[2],p1[2];
int x,y,z;
pipe(p);
x= fork();

if (x>0){//père or parent

close(p[0]);
dup2(p[1],1);
execlp("ls","ls","-l",NULL);
close(p[1]);

}
else{ // fils du père or child of parent
pipe(p1);
z=fork();
if(z>0){ //fils du père or child of parent

close(p[1]);
close(p1[0]);
dup2(p[0],0);
dup2(p1[1],1);
execlp("grep","grep","sthg",NULL);
close(p[0]);
close(p1[1]);

}
else{ //fils du fils or sub-child

close(p[0]);
close(p[1]);
close(p1[1]);
dup2(p1[0],0);
execlp("wc","wc","-l",NULL);
close(p1[0]);

}

}
return 0;
}
```